# How to play RTSP video url into EXOPlayer

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, rtsp, exoplayer

I am developing an application and into that I have used ExoPlayer from google, it is working like charm, now I want to add RTSP support into my application but using Exoplayer I am not able to play that, please any one can help me for this, if any one have another option please share it with me.

```
val playerView = findViewById<PlayerView>(R.id.simple_player)

        playerView.player = player

        val rtmpDataSourceFactory = RtmpDataSourceFactory()

        val url = mVideoPath
        val videoSource = ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(rtmpDataSourceFactory)
            .createMediaSource(Uri.parse("rtsp://192.168.1.74/12"))

        player.prepare(videoSource)

        player.playWhenReady = true
```

lOG

E/ExoPlayerImplInternal: Source error.
    net.butterflytv.rtmp_client.RtmpClient$RtmpIOException
        at net.butterflytv.rtmp_client.RtmpClient.open(RtmpClient.java:56)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ext.rtmp.RtmpDataSource.open(RtmpDataSource.java:60)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.StatsDataSource.open(StatsDataSource.java:83)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ExtractorMediaPeriod$ExtractingLoadable.load(ExtractorMediaPeriod.java:885)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:381)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)

Comment: just pass rtsp link to exo player is works...

Comment: it is not working, getting source error

Comment: which exactly error are you getting?

Comment: share logcat...

Comment: @ShivamOberoi, I have edited post please check

Comment: check if it is working on vlc player or not?? just pass the url

Comment: yes in vlc it is working properly

Answer (score 1):

It seems RTSP support is not in for [the regular ExoPlayer release](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/tree/release-v2), and they still have an [open ticket to add RTSP support](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/pull/3854), but there is a [git branch with RTSP support](https://github.com/portizb/ExoPlayer/tree/release-v2-rtsp).

You are using RtmpDataSourceFactory, you could try using RtspMediaSource.Factory instead.

You could also read up on the [difference between RTMP and RTSP](https://www.red5pro.com/blog/5-ways-to-decide-between-rtmp-vs-rtsp/).

Answer (score 1):

ExoPlayer has provided a patch for Rtsp streaming it seems. I am using ExoPlayer v2.15.0, which is latest one and included Rtsp streaming support in this. But still we are unable to stream "rtsp://192.168.0.26:554/11" these kind of urls. At the same time VLC is able to stream such kind of urls too.

Below is my piece of code to stream given rtsp url

```
    MediaSource mediaSource =
            new RtspMediaSource.Factory().setForceUseRtpTcp(true)
                    .createMediaSource(MediaItem.fromUri("rtsp://192.168.0.26:554/11"));
```

getting **Source error** with this.

Log:
ExoPlayerImplInternal: Playback error
com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException: Source error
Caused by: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: Host unreachable

Note: We have connected the devices within the same network!!!

Answer (score 0):

val rtspUri = "rtsp://"YOUR_IP_ADDRESS":"PORT"/stream1"

```
    val mediaSource: MediaSource =
        RtspMediaSource.Factory().createMediaSource(MediaItem.fromUri(rtspUri))

    exoPlayer = SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(this).build()

    exoPlayer.setMediaSource(mediaSource)
    exoPlayer.prepare()
    exoPlayer.playWhenReady = true
    val playerView = findViewById<PlayerView>(R.id.exoPlayerView)
    playerView.player = exoPlayer

}

override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    // Release the player when the activity is destroyed.
    exoPlayer.release()
}
```

//CONNECT YOUR DEVICES AS SAME NETWORK